# collision detection on game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple Javascript and Jquery game in which a user controls a blue ball and has to avoid red balls.  I attempted to make a collision detection system that would get rid of the red balls when one was touched.  This works however it occasionally detects a collision when there isn't one and I cannot figure out why.  I made a jsfiddle of the game.  By the way, I commented out the function which makes the red balls move so that it would be easier to test the collisions.  Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/clayjames/bxcffwty/4/

Here is the javascript for the game so far:

```
var keyDown = function() {
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37 :
            $("#blue").css("marginLeft","-=40");
            blue.xcordinate = blue.xcordinate - 40;
            check();
            break;
        case 38 :
            $("#blue").css("marginTop","-=40");
            blue.ycordinate = blue.ycordinate - 40;
            check();
            break;
        case 39 :
            $("#blue").css("marginLeft","+=40");
            blue.xcordinate = blue.xcordinate + 40;
            check();
            break;
        case 40 :
            $("#blue").css("marginTop","+=40");
            blue.ycordinate = blue.ycordinate + 40;
            check();
            break;
        };
    });
};

var redX = [0];
var redY = [0];
var loop = 0;
var createRed = function() {
    var randTop = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*600);
    var randLeft = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*1308);
    $("body").append($("<div></div>").addClass("red").css("marginTop",randTop).css("marginLeft",randLeft));
    redX[loop] = randLeft;
    redY[loop] = randTop;
    loop++;
}

var redMovement = function(){
    var redDirection = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 4);
    switch(redDirection) {
        case 1 :
            $(".red").animate({"marginLeft": "-=20"});
            break;
        case 2 :
            $(".red").animate({"marginLeft": "+=20"});
            break;
        case 3 :
            $(".red").animate({"marginTop": "-=20"});
            break;
        case 4 :
            $(".red").animate({"marginTop": "+=20"});
    };
};

var blue = {
    xcordinate: 630,
    ycordinate: 320
}

var xMatch = false;
var yMatch = false;

var check = function() {
    for(x = 0; x < redX.length; x++){
        if(((redX[x] - 25) <= blue.xcordinate + 25 && blue.xcordinate + 25 <= (redX[x] + 25)) || ((redX[x] - 25) <= blue.xcordinate - 25 && blue.xcordinate - 25 <= (redX[x] + 25))) {
        xMatch = true;
    };
};
for(y = 0; y < redY.length; y++){
    if(((redY[y] - 25) <= blue.ycordinate + 25 && blue.ycordinate + 25 <= (redY[y] + 25)) || ((redY[y] - 25) <= blue.ycordinate - 25 && blue.ycordinate - 25 <= (redY[y] + 25))) {
        yMatch = true;
    };
};
if (xMatch === true && yMatch === true) {
    $(".red").remove();
};
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#blue").hide()
    $(".red").remove()
    $("#border").hide()
    setInterval(function(){
    $("h5").fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500)
    },1000);
    $("body").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var clayRocks = setInterval(createRed,10000);
            $("h1, h5").remove();
            $("#blue, #border").show();
        };
    });
    keyDown();
    //setInterval(redMovement,500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

testing the collision between 2 balls is easy (compared to others shapes), you have to calculates the distance of the 2 balls (using pythagore théorem) and see if this distance is less than the sum of the radius of the 2 balls.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably easier to just use absolute value, like this:

```
for (x = 0; x < redX.length; x++) {
    if (Math.abs(redX[x] - blue.xcordinate) <= 25) {
        xMatch = true;
    };
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/73t332ek/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the only issue, but your `check` function is flawed. What it currently does is check if there is a collision on the x-coordinate with *any* red ball and a collision on the y-coordinate with *any (other!)* red ball. It does not enforce that both collisions occur on the *same* red ball.

By the way, this is a rather strange and inaccurate of way of detecting collisions between spherical balls: the natural one is to check if the euclidean distance between the centers is less than the sum of the radiuses, i.e

```
function collides(blueX, blueY, blueR, redX, redY, redR) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(blueX - redX, 2) + Math.pow(blueY - redY, 2)) < blueR + redR;
}
```